# Laravel Load part of page

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a Laravel 4 page,

I already have all my routes defined and my main layout with the contents that is dynamic for each route view.

What I'm facing now, is that every time I change the view, the whole page is reloaded!!
So all the menu images, css, javascripts are reloaded..

Is there any way to make it to just reload the content section?

Comment: you could do a ajax load of the content only, so you split the base alyout from the content, and then make a route to for the content load

Comment: @SebastianKraft is correct. You need to do AJAX. This really isn't anything to do with Laravel specifically.

Comment: So you can have a route that just loads the content? or I need to create a ajax function for each link? I checked bitbucket (their settings page) and it looks like a different route each time, but only the content changes